# Pattern of Y using a "O" string

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript code for the **`Y`** pattern but in the bottom part, it is not in the center what's wrong with my code? will accept odd numbers

```js
const char = "Y";
const size = 5; //all odd numbers
let output = ""
if (char === 'Y') {
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          if (i === j && i < size / 2 || j === size / 2 && i >= size / 2 || i + j === size - 1 && i < size / 2 || (j === 0  && i >= size / 2))
          {
            output += 'O';
          } else {
            output += ' ';
          }
        }
        output += '\n';
      }
    }
    
console.log(output);
```

I expect to have this output:

```
O   O
 O O 
  O  
  O    
  O
```

Comment: Your last condition is `j === 0`, you want it to be `2` instead. But honestly, this code is not really doing much improvement over hard-coding the ASCII art directly...

Comment: @Kaiido how about all odd numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `j === 0` to `j === 2` will solve this problem. For work universally, just use `j === (size - 1) / 2`

```js
const char = "Y";
const size = 5;
let output = ""
if (char === 'Y') {
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          if (i === j && i < size / 2 || j === size / 2 && i >= size / 2 || i + j === size - 1 && i < size / 2 || (j === (size - 1) / 2  && i >= size / 2)) 
          {
            output += 'O';
          } else {
            output += ' ';
          }
        }
        output += '\n';
      }
    }
    
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What about size= 50 ?

Comment: @Jordy how about all odd numbers?

Comment: Just use `j === (size - 1) / 2`

Comment: You're welcome for school